# Is there a way to import data from multiple excel files into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of excel files (with tables) in a folder that I want to import into SQL Server.
Is there a loop or some code that I can write in SQL that will go to file path, open the file and import the data into the table? 
(I have data for each state so opening 50 tables will be tedious and I am looking to avoid doing so.)

Comment: Sql Server Integration Services can do this: **Loop through Excel Files and Tables by Using a Foreach Loop Container** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/loop-through-excel-files-and-tables-by-using-a-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  Does the ADO.NET connection manager mentioned in the article need to be installed or is it included in SQL Server?

Comment: SSIS is an optional component of most editions of SQL Server.  You can get the designer for SSIS with SQL Server Data Tools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15, which includes everything you need to build and test SSIS packages.

Comment: Is there a way to write the loop with out downloading any software? I am on a company computer and cannot download software.

Comment: Power Query for Excel can do this too.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605  You would load all 50 workbooks into a single workbook using Power Query in Excel, then load that one to SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you for that. That helps a lot. Do you want to make it an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Power Query for Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605) to [combine](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-files-in-a-folder-with-Combine-Binaries-Power-Query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4) the workbooks into a single workbook, and then load that into SQL Server.